# urllib.quote() in Go?

Tags: python, url, go, urllib

Is there any function in Go works the same as urllib.quote(string) in Python? Thank you!
The document page for urllib.quote(): https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Answer (score 2):

[urllib.quote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) is designed to quote the path section of a URL. Go's net/url package does not expose this functionality directly, but you can get at it in a roundabout way:

```
func quote(s string) string {
    return (&url.URL{Path: s}).RequestURI()
}
```

Because the Python function escapes more than it needs to, the quote function here and urllib.quote will not always give the same results.

Go's [QueryEscape](http://godoc.org/net/url#QueryEscape) provides the same functionality as Python's [urlib.quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus).

Answer (score 1):

[`url.QueryEscape`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape)

http://play.golang.org/p/yNZZT-Xmfs

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(url.QueryEscape("/Hello, playground"))
}

// %2FHello%2C+playground
```

Comment: Example: quote('/~connolly/') yields '/%7econnolly/'.

Comment: Heh. Looks like Go's `url` module is hard-coded to never escape `~`, `_`, `.` or `-`, per [RFC-3986 §2.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.3) which says that their escaped forms *"should not be created by URI producers"*. @lkkeepmoving Are you sure you need to escape `~`?

Comment: @JeremyBanks Yes I hope to escape ~ and not / by default. Basically, a function works same to urllib.quote(string[, safe]).

Answer (score 0):

Since [version 1.8](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#net_url), Go has [url.PathEscape](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#PathEscape) to quote the path section of a URL just as `urllib.quote(string`) does for Python.